# Procedural dependencies in an OOP application

Tags: php, oop, functional-programming, code-organization

Despite the number of similar questions, I haven't yet managed to find any such concrete answer (*or at least a strongly opinionated individual*)

I've (*at this time*) decided to use "helper" classes, which are simply aggregates of static methods in a class, fittingly named `String` for example. The class itself has no prospect of being an object instance, and has no reason to.

Now I've noticed many people consider this abuse. I do too, and have only resolved to maintain this approach for the benefits of code organization and (*more importantly*) auto-loading.

```
String::keysplode('|', 'apple|banana|coconut', array('a', 'b', 'c'));
```

Here we have `keysplode()`. It performs `explode()` on the given string, with the given delimiter, then calls `trim()` on each element. The resulting array is passed with the array argument to `array_combine()`. The result?

```
array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'coconut');
```

Great! Fancy! Who cares?

The point is, this function really doesn't belong in a class. Right now it lives at `\Package\Common\String::keysplode()`, and while that's a nice place for it, I can see how that is considered "abuse".

I have a plethora of these functions, ones that belong in the `array_*` or  `str_*` pseudo-namespace, and elsewhere. The further problem is, my "genuine" classes, ones that leverage OOP correctly (*or so I believe*) use these functions intimately.

**The "question", as it were, is where should functions like this go?**

When we create functions that extend the "core" functionality of a language, where do we put these functions? Furthermore, how do we manage the dependencies created upon the functions by other parts of an application?

Comment: This might be more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is vastly subjective and completely non-constructive.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal -- I beg to differ. This is a surely a common issue experienced by many working with PHP and other languages which were procedural from inception, and have only now began moving towards an OOP paradigm. I understand solutions can be application specific, however certainly someone experienced can shed some insight on common practices or approaches to dealing with such issues.

Comment: @Bracketworks: I never disputed any of that. I said it's subjective and non-constructive, and as such this is not the right place for it.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal -- Where would you suggest I seek out such information? It's troubling when you build intuitive parts to an application, but are then stuck simply trying to name and place them.

Comment: @Bracketworks: Some message board perhaps? programmers.SE tends to edge closer to this sort of stuff, too.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal -- Fair enough. I concede to the closing votes; however should I vote this question be moved to Programmers, or should I simply delete this one and reword it for that board?

Comment: @Bracketworks: A migration vote is fine. You can always edit it there if required (don't think it would be though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting library functions into a static class has been a PHP idiom because PHP lacked namespaces and the syntax for static methods is similar to the syntax for accessing package functions in Perl.

Now that PHP has namespaces, the clear answer is to put these methods into namespaces (and no longer static classes). While I think that this will be a slow transition (because so many people are still not on PHP 5.3, and many people are on shared hosts), the adjustment is readily apparent and hopefully framework and library developers accept this new idiom (which is standard for other languages with namespaces like C# and Perl).

```
<?php

namespace Foo;

function foo () {
    echo 'foo';
}

namespace Bar;

use Foo;

Foo\foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion developers are developing within an exact language wether is that PHP or anything else. Most of the time a class written in PHP will be used in PHP, so you don't really need to care about core functions. Using them is absolutely a correct way, you only have to take care of those functions' changes.

If you consider using another library's services, that's a whole other thing, but in this case, you don't have to worry about the core functionalities of a language.